# MuPDF insert page fails

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-generation, mupdf

I need to create a new PDF document. I have found some code regarding this in MuPDF library and tried the following. I simply followed the example here https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/mupdf/blob/master/docs/examples/pdf-create.js

```
PDFDocument pdf = new PDFDocument();
PDFObject font = pdf.addFont(new Font("Times-Roman"));
pdf.addObject(font);

// Create content stream.
Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
buffer.writeLine("10 10 280 330 re s");
buffer.writeLine("q 200 0 0 200 50 100 cm /Im0 Do Q");
buffer.writeLine("BT /Tm 16 Tf 50 50 TD (Hello, world!) Tj ET");

PDFObject page = pdf.addPage(new Rect(0,0,300,350), 0, font, buffer);
pdf.insertPage(-1, page);
pdf.save(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+"/output.pdf", "pretty,ascii,compress-images,compress-fonts");
```

I'm getting the following error when inserting the page to the pdf document.

```
2021-01-25 16:08:24.306 32539-32539/com.artifex.mupdf_test E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in 
MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
2021-01-25 16:08:24.309 32539-32539/com.artifex.mupdf_test E/MessageQueue-JNI: 
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: at is not a valid page
    at com.artifex.mupdf.fitz.PDFDocument.insertPage(Native Method)
    at com.artifex.mupdf_test.ChooseDocActivity.onListItemClick(ChooseDocActivity.java:599)
```

I cannot figure out what is the issue in this and I'm stuck for days. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Seems you're using the Android SDK (Java) and trying to run JavaScript examples?

Comment: The same set of classes and methods are available on the Android SDK too. The mentioned code block is also working fine except the insert page line. Without the insert page code line, a file is saved in the given location when executed the code block.

Comment: You removed the resources dict from the example. It defines the `/Tm` and `/Im0` commands. Try adding them back in or just start again from the example..